# After switching from Django's default Users model to an AbstractUser model, Admin is looking for a Users_groups table

Tags: django

It became apparent the default User model wasn't going to work for me, nor extending it, so decided to make an `AbstractUser` model to use an existing table.

Pretty much have everything working, except when I go to edit a user in Django Admin, I am getting an error:

```
ProgrammingError at /adminauthentication/user/100826/change/
(1146, "Table 'test_db.Users_groups' doesn't exist")
```

Not sure why it is trying to find this table as I haven't specified it, don't recall in the documentation needing to specify it, and thought `AbstractUser` would use other default tables that created with the initial `migrate` (e.g. `auth_group` or something).

Not quite sure how to resolve, but I am looking into it.

```
# ./admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

---

```
# ./models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

# Extend the User model
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    ip_whitelist_1 = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    ip_whitelist_2 = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    ip_whitelist_3 = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    password_changed = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    security_q1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_q2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_a1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_a2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField(db_column='role', blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    login_unlock_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    challenge_unlock_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='active', blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(db_column='created', blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
    ]
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Users'
```

Comment: Did you delete your database and recreate all the migrations when you switched to the new model? It's documented that the migrations system doesn't do well with migrating from the built in user to a substitute one.

Comment: Deleted the Django related tables and started new project copying over any pertinent files from the old project. Yes, was of the issue of changing to custom models mid-project per the documentation:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project. Since `AbstractUser` is mostly using the default User settings, and they both create the same tables with the initial `migrate`, it seems like just using the default User I would have run into this issue as well since it should have been looking for the same table (I would think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally took the time to look at it as I was just going to let it go since it wasn't really hurting anything where I am currently at.

Maybe its in the documentation, or maybe the answer has been posted elsewhere, but I didn't look.

I instead looked at another DB I have using the the defaults. Three tables were missing:

```
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions
```

Since I changed `auth_user` to just `Users` per it being an exiting table that one wasn't an issue. It didn't make the other two which would have to be called `Users_groups` and `Users_user_permissions`. Not sure why they weren't made with the initial `./manage.py makemigrations` --> `./manage.py migrate`.

Anyway, this took care of it in my case, but if your user table other than `Users` it won't work.

```
CREATE TABLE Users_user_permissions (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id integer,
    permission_id integer
);

CREATE TABLE Users_groups (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id integer,
    group_id integer
);
```

Comment: user_id is users_id